# How to check if a particular string is present in a List of strings , but also its Index

Tags: python, list

I want to know,  is there a way to check if a string is present in the list of strings ;

I want some thing like :

```
a = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
b = "three"
if b in a:
    # return index of a
else:
    # do something else
```

Comment: Try running that and see what happens. :)

Comment: What you have written will work exactly.

Comment: thanks people , can't delete the question now coz a few people answered it

Comment: Thanks for the help people; I have made a few changes in the question can u please look at it again , thanks again @NamitSingal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is return the index of b inside of a, if b is present, and so something else if it is not, try this : -

```
a = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
b = "three"
try:
    print a.index(b) #if inside the function, use return
except:
    #do something2
```

Answer (score 0):

As other experts said, I would highly recommend you try it with your own Python 2.x/3.x environment.

If you for some reason don't have it in hand, try some online IDEs, for example https://ideone.com/